# Response of a REST API into Fragment - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, rest

I'm new in developing APP in android. I would like to develop an APP divided in fragment and each fragment is populated with datas obtained calling REST APIs.

I followed different tutorial but I have this issue: The fragment didn't display anything.

I start my project from the "Tabbed Activity" in android studio:

Here my fragment (where i call the api):

```
public class Calendar extends Fragment {

private static final String baseUrl = "https://xxx";
private static final String events = "/wp-json/sportspress/v2/events";
EventsJsonObjectToMatchesConverter converter;

ArrayList<Matches> matches = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout,container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    this.getEvents();

    ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.matches);

    MatchesAdapter adapter = new MatchesAdapter(this.getContext(),
            R.layout.matches_layout,
            matches);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getEvents() {

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    String url =getString(R.string.baseUrl) + getString(R.string.eventsEndpoit);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    Matches match = new Matches();
                    match.setHomeTeam("simone");
                    match.setAwayTeam("gaspa");
                    match.setResultHome(2);
                    match.setResultAway(1);
                    match.setDate("05/10/2021 - 10:00");
                    matches.add(match);

                    System.out.println(matches.size());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put(
                    "Authorization",
                    String.format("Basic %s", Base64.encodeToString(
                            String.format("%s:%s", getString(R.string.user), getString(R.string.password)).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)));
            return params;
        }


    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);


}


}
```

and here my adapter:

```
public class MatchesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Matches> {

private ArrayList<Matches> matchList;

public MatchesAdapter(Context context, int matches_layout, ArrayList<Matches> matches) {
    super(context, matches_layout);
    this.matchList = matches;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    int phraseIndex  = position;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.matches_layout,parent, false);
    }

    TextView home = convertView.findViewById(R.id.squadra_casa);
    TextView away = convertView.findViewById(R.id.squadra_trasferta);
    TextView home_result = convertView.findViewById(R.id.risultato_casa);
    TextView away_result = convertView.findViewById(R.id.risultato_trasferta);
    TextView group = convertView.findViewById(R.id.girone);
    TextView date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.data_ora);

    home.setText(matchList.get(position).getHomeTeam());
    away.setText(matchList.get(position).getAwayTeam());
    home_result.setText(matchList.get(position).getResultHome());
    away_result.setText(matchList.get(position).getResultAway());
    group.setText(matchList.get(position).getGroup());
    date.setText(matchList.get(position).getDate());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

I run the application but i don't see anyhing:

[image]

NOTE: I mocked the object Match in the onResponse() method to test the code. I've seen that the Rest API is called correctly and return the desired datas

Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems quite well written from brief look at the code. The main point you are missing is that the API call is asynchronous and the adapter is populated BEFORE the API returns any result. Try populating the adapter in the OnResponse callback of your StringRequest call, something like this (sry im not trying to run it, but I think it might be helpful just to give you a hint):

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                matches = ParseTextResultToMatchesObjects(response);
                adapter = new MatchesAdapter(this.getContext(),
                    R.layout.matches_layout,
                    matches);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
    ...
```

EDIT:
For anyone concerned about this in the future: The whole operation was placed inside onViewCreated, instead of onCreateView, which resulted in more complications (am not sure why tho), nevertheless what I wrote about asynchronity of the operations and populating the adapter at a wrong time stands...

Comment: P.s.: The code provided is probably wrong, but I am quite sure, that the error is from the ASYNC behavior I described. Hope it helps.

Comment: P.s.s.: Put breakpoint to MatchesAdapter contructor and inside the OnResponse callback and see which fires first ;)

Comment: I've tried like you sad but the result is the same. Going in Debug, if I try your solution the first breakpoint "fired" is into the onResponse method and after in the adpater's constructor, with my code is the viceversa

Comment: Using my code, the app first execute the onViewCreated method (creating and setting the adapter into the listView) and after it calls the onResponse method

Comment: Well, thats it... You are populating the list without data, thats why you see empty page. Call the adapter constructor inside the onResponse call and you should be good to go... (and remove the first call to construct the adapter)

Comment: I changed my code, but it is the same :(  `public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Matches match = new Matches(); ...
                        matches.add(match);
                        MatchesAdapter adapter = new MatchesAdapter(context,R.layout.matches_layout,matches);
                        lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.matches);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
`

Comment: Hello. It seems to me that the listview is already created and it doesnt redraw with the new adapter. Try this:
1) Call lv.notifyDataSetChanged()
2) adapter.clear();
      adapter.addAll(matches);

Comment: I solved this, i put the call "this.getEvents();" into the "onCreateView" method and inside the "onResponse" method i set the adapter. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the whole operation is in "onViewCreated", not in "onCreateView", yea, that makes differece... Accept the answer maybe? ;)

Comment: I've accepted the answer.....in change, can you help me also with another question? :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945984/populate-tablelayout-with-restapi